# Array push always empty after push (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

everytime i try to enter in the form and submit it the console.log always returns [].

i am trying to receive ex:[ { id: 123456, username: Rob, email: rob@rob, password: (will be incrypted)} ]

edit: i know an array user isnt a good thing. i've been following a tutorial, ill later add it to a database

```
const users = []

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.boby.password, 10)
    users.push({
      id: Date.now().toString(),
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPass,
    })
    res.redirect('/login')
  } catch {
    res.redirect('/register')
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(users))
})
```

.EJS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Register</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>register</h1>
    <form class="" method="post" action="/register">
      <div>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required />
      </div>
      <div><button type="submit">Register</button></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<a href="/login">Login</a>
```

Comment: You console.log is after the redirect code

Comment: Redirecting to `/register` on *any* exception is a good way to miss important errors. An exception is probably being thrown, so remove the `try`/`catch` to find out what it is. (For example, the typo “boby” in `req.boby.password`.)

Comment: @jfriend00 An array isn't necessarily a great user store, but I don't see how the concept is different to any other shared store? A db connection will be usually be shared among all possible users. If they use a persistent store with an array like interface code would be the same.

Comment: I mean you'd probably import `users` from somewhere shared... but general concept wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to log the error in catch block.

```
//const users = []    not good

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)  // a little type-O here boby instead of body
    const users = [{
      id: Date.now().toString(),
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPass,
    }]
    console.log(JSON.stringify(users))
    res.redirect('/login')
  } catch (error){
    console.error(error);  /// log the error here
    res.redirect('/register')
  }
//  console.log(JSON.stringify(users))  // not needed
})
```

Comment: best to include the error `catch (error) { console.error(error) }`

Comment: @DevLoverUmar lol wowthank you. all because of that typo i was going mad searching for answers

Comment: @DevLoverUmar cool. one more nit :) `JSON.stringify()` loses the `.stack` and `.message` properties on an `Error` as they are not enumerable `JSON.stringify(new Error('nope')) === '{}``